# BezierCurve extrudes too much

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bezier-curves

I'm trying to extrude a BezierCurve in Blender. I do that with pressing <kbd>E</kbd> but it extrudes a little too much. Seems like, it is defined how much it should extrude by default.
Is there any way to change that?

This is what happens after I press <kbd>E</kbd>. I can't control the length of extrusion!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: normaly it doesnt jump to a predefind distance after hitting "e". Normally it stays at the same location till you move your coursor. In Your screenshot you dont have snapping on, so that shoulndt be the problem?

Comment: @AM I added another picture to demonstrate what happens after I push e. The curve gets too long, more than I need. I can't control the length of extrusion!

Comment: strange! could you upload a file, maby there is something wrong in the settings

Comment: @AM I just uploaded my blender file.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Maby we got another misunderstanding? Did you try to scale or manipulate the handles, so the curve-point hasnt that much influence. If that has nothing to do with it, could you paraphrase your problem please

Comment: what happens if you hit "e" and move your coursor before hitting enter oder clicking? Doesnt the curve-point move with you mouse-cousor?

Comment: It did happen with me. I solved it by deselecting "Snap During Transform" icon.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just your Handle Type.

If the Handle Type is'Free' or 'Aligned', the default behavior of <kbd>E</kbd> extrude is to copy the source vertex, along with its control points. If the control points are extended, that will also create a segment of some length. If the extrusion is from a 'Vector' or 'Automatic' (unadjusted) vertex, the system has the opportunity to adjust the front-facing handle of the previous vertex, as you extend the curve.